# why elements are not in one row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why this two elements are not in one row? I use bootstrap 4

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2">
         <a class="logo"><img class="logo__img"  src="./img/logo.png"/></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 hamburger">
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZha3.png)

```
.hamburger span {
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 2.4rem;
}
```

Comment: using lg, so check its breakpoint

Comment: I think you didn't share all of your code, which makes it hard to see what the problem is. Could you share all the relevant code in a JSFiddle?

Comment: They're in the same row, which browser are you using?

Comment: You can see all code in public repo https://github.com/csergey8/travelly_template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add the cdn ,

if you didnt add the cdn ,bootstrap wont work

Comment: Yes cdn was added

Comment: there must be some problem with the links ,try this  cdn it worked fr me               
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah It was look like a bug with CDN. Thanks for all